# Solspace Calendar One-way Sync with Outlook?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I know that I can import data from a .ics file when creating a new calendar, but is it possible to do some sort of synchronization with Outlook on certain intervals?

I have been tasked with building a Intranet and I'm trying to decide if I can save costs by building in EE rather than doing custom development.

With synchronization, I need to have it run at an interval (cron job to hit a URL?) and be able to add/update/remove events.

I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `{exp:calendar:icalendar}` (http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/icalendar/), you can output an .ics file containing event entries from a calendar. This .ics file will be presented to your browser as a downloadable file (i.e. it's not outputted to the screen. You're prompted to download the file).

If Outlook can read this .ics file (really depends on the calendaring app whether it accepts a downloadable file when hitting a URL), then you could indeed import this information into Outlook (although I have never tried). It's not really synchronization but more exporting Calendar data, which can be used for import in other apps/software (eg. iCal).

Comment: I want to go the other way around. The client wants to be able to manage their calendar entries in Outlook and I want the calendar in EE to periodically check for changes and add/update/remove accordingly.